# Java: Packaging classes with cross-module-usage

Tags: java

In my project (a parser for various formats), I packaged the modules by functionality but there are a few classes which are needed by every module.

Now I'm not sure what's the best practice here:

- Should every module/package have a duplicate of the class? The compiler will probably optimize this anyway, won't it?
- Create a "Shared" package? This doesn't feel right...
- Other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't package duplicates of the class, that could cause you some endless headaches, because the same class file contents loaded by different classloaders is not considered to be the same class at all by Java, so you'll get impossible to understand error messages. And if all your jars are in the same class loader, only the first class will be loaded, so you may as well put it in one place only.

I would certainly package utility classes in their own jar and have a dependency from all the other packages, as is the case with other libraries you may use etc. You can even use the classpath attribute of the manifest to reference the library easily.

Comment: I ended up creating a "Utility" package. Seems like the cleanest way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create an abstract class and provide implentation separately in each class and package them separately.